# Reading a file from a created directory in the isolatedstorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to read a written file in a created directory in the isolated storage.. The file is actually being created. but when it is being read it there is an exception "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream."...

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!storage.DirectoryExists("CourseworkDirectory"))
        storage.CreateDirectory("CourseworkDirectory");

    XElement Coursework = new XElement(CourseworkID);
    XDocument  _doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), Coursework);
    IsolatedStorageFileStream location = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("CourseworkDirectory\\"+CourseworkID, System.IO.FileMode.Create, storage);
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(location);  

    _doc.Save(file);//saving the XML document as the file
    file.Close();
    file.Dispose();//disposing the file
    location.Dispose();
}
```

Reading the file....

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    string searchpath = System.IO.Path.Combine("CourseworkDirectory", "*.*");

    foreach (string filename in storage.GetFileNames(searchpath))
    {
        XElement _xml;
        IsolatedStorageFileStream location = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open, storage);
```

It is actually getting the file name but there is an exception at this point.

Comment: did you try storage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

Comment: Yes I did... It actually sees the filename but it gives the same problem

Comment: The issue is with the directory I created... When I tried to use the IsolatedStorageFile it worked very.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing this---

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storage.OpenFile(app.getSettingsPath,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream ))
   {
      string line;
      while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         // do your work here
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me: Hope it works for you too

```
        String sb;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, myIsolatedStorage));

                sb = reader.ReadToEnd();

                reader.Close();
            }

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sb))
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(sb);
            }
        }
```

If this doesn't work, then maybe your file doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Milani i try this and Works for me, but i have one question, if i want to take the XML file to use inside of  `var xml = XDocument.Load("path").ToString();` i know the method "Load" takes Stream as parameter but i don't know how to use,if you could help me!